# Replacing the IN operator in Power BI RLS

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi, row-level-security

I want to ask if its possible to use something like IN operator in Power BI RLS DAX.
The approach I am using now seems very convoluted to me, and I want to ask if it could be done better and simpler.

I have two types of identifiers in my Fact table: **Code** and **GroupCode**. **Code** is **NOT NULL** identifier and can have multiple unique **GroupCodes** and **GroupCode** can be **NULL** and can be assigned to multiple **Code**.
Example Fact table:

| Code | GroupCode | Client |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | John |
| 1 | b | Susie |
| 1 | c | Mark |
| 2 | a | John |
| 2 | NULL | Mary |
| 3 | b | Susie |

I want to create report where User enters by Code, but see all rows with it GroupCode.
In SQL it would be:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE GroupCode IN (SELECT GroupCode FROM TABLE WHERE Code = '2') or Code = '2'
```

For now I created *Dictionary* table from my Fact table with **Code** and **CodeDict**, where `CodeDict = ISNULL(GroupCode, Code)`. Also added **CodeDict** column to Fact table to create relation based on it, between Dict and Fact tables. Should be **(1:*)**, but it shows **(*:*)**.
Example Dict table:

| Code | GroupCode |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 1 | c |
| 2 | a |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | b |

[image: Power BI Example]

As for RLS rule it is set on Dict table as `[Code] = @USERPRINCIPALNAME()`. 
So for example if User open report using **Code** = 2. RLS will filter Dict table so **CodeDict** will be **(a, 2)** and by them, it will filter Fact table to shows rows with **Code=(1, 2)**

It's very convoluted approach and I don't like it, but I have no idea I could make it other way. I  worry about **(*:*)** relation and that I have to create Bridge Dict table.

What do you think about this approach to this problem? 
Is there a way to implement IN operator in RLS rule?

Comment: you can use dax to filter out. can you show the implemented RLS for this particular solution?

Comment: RLS is pretty simple it's only this: `[Code] = USERPRINCIPALNAME()` But I want all data with *[Code]s* connected to *[CodeDict]* from filtered by RLS *[Code]*